# How To Make Nesting Array From Existing Array in php

Tags: php, arrays

What I Need

- i Need to create nesting array from existing array.
- if in array both values type are same .
- group according their type.
- like array[1] type is same array[2] type so i need to group them in single nested array.

here is the array structure

```
                  $data=$event['data']['pricing_detail'];
                  [1] => Array
                  (
                  [type] => General Public Tickets Adult
                  [amount] => 50
                  [comment] => (Working Days)
                  )

                  [2] => Array
                  (
                  [type] => General Public Tickets Adult
                  [amount] => 80
                  [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
                  )
```

- i need output like

  ```
                [1] => Array
                (
                  [type] => General Public Tickets Adult
                  [metadata]=>array
                     (
                         [0] =>array
                          (
                             [amount] => 50
                             [comment] => (Working Days)
                          )
                          [1]=>array
                           (
                            [amount] => 80
                            [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
                           )
                    )
                 )
  ```

code snippet

```
         $data=$event['data']['pricing_detail'];
         $metadata = array();
        foreach($data as $key => $value)
        {

                if($value[1]['type'] == $value[2]['type'])
            {

                $metadata[$key]['amount'] = $value['amount'];
                print_r($metadata);

            }
            else
            {
                  echo  "not matched";  

            }
        }
```

- Problem im facing im not able to make logic so to get desired result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop your array, storing the types and the array they belong to. 
Then loop the types and add te values.

```
//store types and the arrays the belong to    
foreach($data as $k=>$v){
    $type[$v['type']][]=$k;
    }

//loop types, creating result array
foreach($type as $k=>$v){
    $tmp=array(
        'type'=>$k,
        'metadata'=>array()
        );
      //loop all the arrays of this type
    foreach($v as $w){
                //store in TMP
    $t=array(
        'amount' => $vals[$w]['amount'],
        'comment' => $vals[$w]['comment']
                     );
                //sort TMP on EMPTY value
    usort($t,function ($a, $b) {
        if($a == '' && $b != '') return 1;
        if($b == '' && $a != '') return -1;
        if($b == 0){return 1;}
        return 0; 
        });
    //store 
    $tmp['metadata'][]=$t;
          }
    $result[]=$tmp;
    }

echo '<pre>'.print_r($result,true).'<pre>';
```

Example:

```
$data=array(
    1 => Array(
        'type' => 'General Public Tickets Adult',
      'amount' => 50,
      'comment' => '(Working Days)'),
      2 => Array    (
       'type' => 'General Public Tickets Adult',
       'amount' => 80,
       'comment' => '(Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)'),
    3 => Array  (
       'type' => 'Special Tickets Children',
       'amount' => 300,
       'comment' => '(Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)'),
    4 => Array  (
       'type' => 'Special Tickets Children',
       'amount' => 10000,
       'comment' => '(Monday afternoon)')
);
```

result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array(
            [type] => General Public Tickets Adult
            [metadata] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [amount] => 50
                            [comment] => (Working Days)
                        )
                    [1] => Array(
                            [amount] => 80
                            [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
                        )
                )
        )

    [1] => Array(
            [type] => Special Tickets Children
            [metadata] => Array(
                    [0] => Array(
                            [amount] => 300
                            [comment] => (Saturday/ Sunday/ Holiday)
                        )
                    [1] => Array(
                            [amount] => 10000
                            [comment] => (Monday afternoon)
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

**[edit]** updated with `usort` for sorting empty 'comments';

**[edit]** added line to `usort` to prevent unwanted sorting when tickets = 0;

[And a fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e921c23e38a3bde49cf28e0edd7a1a89b0807587)

Comment: could you help me issue  how to sort [comment] according data say structure if comment "string" should come at top else should be at lower index of array

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand exactly what you need

Comment: how t sort comment if [comment] is not empty there it should at top otherwise if [comment] is empty we should place empty comments lower order

Comment: You mean you'd like to switch them if the comment is empty? So the result array becomes `[0] => Array( [comment] => 'dadada', [amount] =>10)` or `[0] => Array( [amount] =>99,[comment] => empty)` ?

Comment: yes i just want to sort associative array according to empty/data

Comment: Updated with `usort` for empty values

Comment: its not sorting according my result [metadata] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                        )

                )

Comment: code above is not working for sorting the empty array

Comment: no there is bug if you put 1=>array(
    'type' => 'General Public Tickets Adult',
    'amount' => 50,
    'comment' => ''
    ),then it does not sort accorting in order if comment are are null should be at lower order

Comment: yup http://www.cropmyimage.net/images/6fcfe646-ad78-4cf9-a075-4a388c5faac7/Screenshot%20from%202014-10-15%2018:08:59.png

Comment: condition of sorting is not working because when you have put comment='' at lower array is already in desc order but when you see you place comment='' at top array then condition fails

Comment: I've created a [new fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ed927b844cc58bbd1be3bfa8b7bc105b2ed6c221) for you. If this isn't what you want, I simply don't understand what you do want.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63110/discussion-between-user3785613-and-michel).

Comment: i just want that [comment]='' then it should be in lower order

Comment: in js fiddle you have not  shown that if [comment] is null then it should be in lower order

Comment: hey mike i have simple issue code foreach($data as $k=>$v){
     $type[$v['type']][]=$k;
     } is not putting in same array of same type not working

Answer (score 1):

You have too create a new tickets array, with first dimention being the contents of type and second dimension being it's original id.

Something like this:

```
$grouped = array();
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $grouped[$value['type']][$key] = $value;
    unset($grouped[$value['type']][$key]["type"]);
}
print_r($grouped);
```

Adjust according to your array structure, I cant see the your actual structure of $data in your samples.

---

If you want to sort a multilevel array, you can use a variation of this function:

```
/**
 * sort an multidimensional array by any of it's fields and return sorted array
 * ex.: $sorted = multisort($data, 'volume', SORT_DESC, 'edition', SORT_ASC);
 * IMPORTANT: This function uses mutlisort and will reindex numeric keys !
 * @param array $data       array to sort
 * @param string $field     name of field to sort by
 * @param int $direction    SORT_DESC or SORT_ASC constant
 * @return array
 */
 function multisort(){
     $args = func_get_args();
     $data = array_shift($args);

     foreach ($args as $n => $field) {
         if (is_string($field)) {
             $tmp = array();
             foreach ($data as $key => $row)
                 $tmp[$key] = $row[$field];
             $args[$n] = $tmp;
         }
     }

     $args[] = &$data;
     call_user_func_array('array_multisort', $args);
     return array_pop($args);
```

}

Used like this:

```
foreach($grouped as $type => &$list)
    $list = multisort($list, 'comment', SORT_DESC);
```

Comment: could you issue how t sort comment if comment is there it should at top otherwise we should place empty comments lower order